# Automation android game test tool

Tags: java, android, testing, automation

I have got a project to create an automated test tool for 3rd party (Source code isn't available) android games.So my question is to what extend can we run an automated test for a game. Is it possible to create such a tool ? If yes please let me how we can do it.

Answer (score 2):

[Robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robotium) seems matching your requirements well. It allows to tap here and there on a running application without having source code access, also search for a text that must appear in response to these taps.

Comment: But I have to create an automated tool. How can I identify where in the screen the tap event should take place. Also since the game is 3rd party games, How will I know the controls of the games (Whether its using touch or tilt event etc)

Comment: Then look into the [source code of Robotium](https://github.com/jayway/robotium/tree/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo) if you wish to learn.